# Converting R data frame to JSON while separating each row into a new JSON object

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have an R dataframe that I want to convert to JSON but I want to have each row inserted into the new JSON object named "traits". I've tried to cbind a traits column as the first column and convert the new dataframe to JSON but that doesn't produce the correct output. I've also tried to append a "traits" : { object to each converted JSON output but that also failed. I'm trying to work within the dataframe then convert it to JSON because toJSON produces a list in brackets [], which I cant' get around either.I'm using jsonlite

```
color = c('red','blue','green')
fruit = c('apple','orange','grape')
animal = c('cat','dog','chicken')
df<- data.frame(color, fruit, animal)
toJSON(df, pretty= TRUE)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[
  { "traits": {
      "color": "red",
      "fruit": "apple",
      "animal": "cat"
  }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
L <- list(list(traits = as.list(df[1,])), 
          list(traits = as.list(df[2,])),
          list(traits = as.list(df[3,])))
```

---

```
> toJSON(L, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
[
  {
    "traits": {
      "color": "red",
      "fruit": "apple",
      "animal": "cat"
    }
  },
  {
    "traits": {
      "color": "blue",
      "fruit": "orange",
      "animal": "dog"
    }
  },
  {
    "traits": {
      "color": "green",
      "fruit": "grape",
      "animal": "chicken"
    }
  }
]
```

To get this list `L` you can do

```
L <- apply(df, 1, function(x) list(traits = as.list(x)))
```

Another way is:

```
df2 <- purrr::transpose(lapply(df, function(x) as.character(x)))
L <- lapply(df2, function(x) list(traits = x))
```

or

```
df <- data.frame(color, fruit, animal, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
L <- lapply(purrr::transpose(df), function(x) list(traits = x))
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. It achieves the traits exactly as wanted but I noticed that it puts each value of the JSON object in brackets though, so it looks like this: "animal" : ["chicken"] instead of "animal" : "chicken"

Comment: @Milan That's why I use `auto_unbox = TRUE`.

Comment: @Milan Nice. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Otherwise your question is considered as non-answered by SO.